# Devise Rspec expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 302

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I have a `user` which I'm creating with FactoryGirl which needs to have a `company` in order to login successfully to my `root_url`.

I'm not having any luck at all stubbing the user method to login.  I've followed [this tutorial](http://willschenk.com/setting-up-testing/) for the Devise portion of the user and needed to amend it a little since my user also requires a `company` to be associated to it.

I've now created a new model/controller called `Scans` that is behind Devise's `authenticate` filter and my first pass at testing it failing with:

```
5) ScansController GET #show returns http success
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
       expected the response to have a success status code (2xx) but it was 302
     # ./spec/controllers/scans_controller_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:127:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The spec is currently:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ScansController, type: :controller do

  before(:all) do
    @user = build(:user)
    @company = build(:company)
    @device = build(:device)
    @scan = build(:scan)
  end

  describe "GET #show" do
    it "returns http success" do
      login_with @user
      get :show, :device_id => @device.id, :id => @scan.id
      expect(response).to render_template(:show)
    end
  end
```

I'm doing a `puts` on the response, because I want to see what's being returned:

```
ScansController
  GET #show
302
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Location"=>"http://test.host/login", "Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
#<Rack::BodyProxy:0x007fb52a7407c0>
```

So, I'm being redirected back to my login page, which tells me that my `login_with` method in `ControllerHelpers` is not working correctly:

```
module ControllerHelpers
  def login_with(user = double('user'), scope = :user)
    current_user = "current_#{scope}".to_sym
    if user.nil?
      allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden, {:scope => scope})
      allow(controller).to receive(current_user).and_return(nil)
    else
      allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return(user)
      allow(controller).to receive(current_user).and_return(user)
    end
  end
end
```

Now, my login functionality does currently work (testing manually).  The first controller that fires after `ApplicationController` is `PagesController#home`:

```
def home
  if current_user && current_user.company
     verify_subscription
     ....
  else
     redirect_to new_company_path
  end
end
```

*If `verify_subscription` fails the user is also sent to `new_company_path`, so that doesn't seem to be related to this issue.*

Based off my rudimentary rspec capabilities, am I right to assume that I'm not even getting close to mimicking a login? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)

Comment: also, where is the `login_with` method used?

Comment: @zetetic updated the rspec method for you... `login_with` is there.

Answer (score 2):

After alot of tinkering I finally got my tests to pass.  I ended up creating a company within my user Factory:

```
after(:build) do |user|
  user.company = create(:company)
end
```